# Docker : Unable to resolve the name of the machine host?

Tags: docker

I installed in a VM centos 7.2 docker. 
As an exampple, my VM name is **${name_vp}** and its IP adress : **${ip_vm}**

I have one contenair for Jenkins (on port **8080**) and another for gitlab (on port **8081**).

When I tried to connect jenkins to gitlab using **http://${ip_vm}:8081** , The connection is established successfully but when I tried **http:${name_vm}:8081** , I have error, Jenkins could not resolve the hostname.

In my brower, if I want to connect on jenkins, I use **http:${name_vm}:8080** and to gitlab I use **http:${name_vm}:8081**

What can I do if I want to use the name of my machine in a contenair to connect to another contenair ? How to resolve the resolution of DNS?

Comment: Make sure the machine's domain is defined, and configured properly in the OS

Comment: It is properly configured in my OS. If i do ping ${vm_name} I can see the IP of my machine